# How can i give free shipping order above RS.500 for only selected City

Tags: magento-1.9, free-shipping, selection

I need to give free shipping to the selecetd city if the order above RS.500 also the city is selected city then the free shipping will be applied.

Answer (score 2):

Out of the box Magento 1.x does not offer the ability to target a specific city with a shopping cart promotion. However, depending on your target region/city you could use a postal code. For example, In the United States, La Crosse WI has 3 possible postal codes, 54601, 54602, 54603.

You could set free shipping to this area by setting the conditional rule of:

```
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
Shipping Postcode  is one of  54601,54602,54603 
Subtotal  equals or greater than  500
```

Then in the Actions tab set:

```
Free Shipping Shipment with Matching Items
```

Now, unfortunately this will not work if the country/city you are targeting does not have a specific postal code you can target.

Comment: Yea, you are right, but when I select the subtotal condition the entire page refreshes and mis the context, what should i do

Answer (score 1):

You can use magento table rate for this

You can use tablerate as `price vs destination`

Take a look this tutorial

http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/shipping/shipping-table-rate.html